# How do I enable the minimap extension into de forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I need to enable the minimap viewer into de Autodesk forge viewer.  The purpose is to navigate in the plan view of the model and at the same time the main window shows the 3d view of the camera. Also that it can switch from one level to the other. Is there any github code or someone could share or help me with this?

Thanks,

Ruben Murray

Answer (score 0):

We can add the extension id into viewer configurations like the `config3d` below in the code. The viewer will load this extension automatically, and open the minimap when activating the first-person navigation.

```
var config3d = {
  ...
  extensions: ['Autodesk.AEC.Minimap3DExtension'],
  ...
};
var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer')
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv, config3d);
viewer.start();
```

Note. please ensure the viewer reference is targeting to v7, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>
```

ref: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/extensions/#step-3-load-the-extension